# How to keep same aspect ratio in different devices with cocos2dx?

Tags: opengl, c++, cocos2d-x

I have been making a board game and I am using cocos2dx. There are two scenes for now, One is main menu and the other is gameplay scene. When I run the apk on tablet with EXACT_FIT resolution policy in AppDelegate.cpp sprites in the scene seems stretched out a little bit. How can I maintain the same aspect ration in all devices and also the positions of game entities? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my games, I choose what is the priority dimension: width or height. If I choose to prioritize WIDTH, I set it in AppDelegate.cpp

```
glview->setDesignResolutionSize(resolutionSize.width, resolutionSize.height, ResolutionPolicy::FIXED_WIDTH);
```

and all my background images have enough height to cover all aspect ratios, based on my design resolution. For example, if my design resolution is 460 x 800, to cover a 19:9 screen we need a 460 x 971 background image.

Then, I set UI components position relative to the safeArea borders

```
auto safeArea = Director::getInstance()->getSafeAreaRect();

someSprite->setPosition(Vec2(safeArea.getMinX() + margin, safeArea.getMaxY() - margin));
```

Hope this answer helps you

Answer (score -1):

`SHOW_ALL` resolution policy. Show all policy will scale up the container to the maximum size in the frame which shows all your content on screen with the original width/height ratio you have set. [Read more here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multiple_Resolution_Policy_for_Cocos2d-JS)

C++ code:

```
glview->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height, kResolutionShowAll);
```